# Android Studio Tela - Bloquear completamente Touch

Tags: java, android, touch

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho uma Activity que finaliza um pedido e insere os dados desse pedido no banco e isso leva um tempinho.... Gostaria de saber se existe algum meio de travar o touch para evitar que o usuário aperte algum botão, textEdit, spinner, listView e afins que possuo na tela... Tentei setar item por item, porém o spinner e o listView não conseguem travar. Queria desativar o touch por completo da tela durante a transmissão de dados e só habilitar novamente quando a transação acabar... Alguém tem uma ideia de um meio para fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode criar uma `thread` para inserção enquanto roda um `dialog` de aguarde. Depois você retorna no `Handler` e fecha o `dialog` @marcio

Comment: tem como desabilitar o touch no dialog? se tiver a ideia é genial

Comment: pq tenho um dialog em outra tela q se vc clicar em qlq lugar ele fecha

Comment: Tem sim, tem a opção `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`

Comment: Para a dialog não fechar, utilize o setCancelable(false). Porém lembre que ao terminar, você tem que dar o dismiss() da Dialog.

Comment: Vou testar aqui e já retorno com o resultado.... Valeu pela ideia =D

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente..... Se tivesse colocado como resposta eu avaliava você.... Mas valeu de qualquer forma... Obrigado!!!!!

Comment: Só um aviso em termos de UX: é uma péssima abordagem impedir o usuário de continuar utilizando o app porque você está fazendo chamadas no background. =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma `thread` para inserção enquanto roda um `dialog` de aguarde. Depois você retorna no `Handler` e fecha o `dialog`. 
Para desabilitar a suspensão do `dialog` utilize o comando `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`

Comment: Funcionou para mim, simples e objetivo... Muito bom!!!